# mysql: find cyrillic or greek text in database

Tags: mysql, select, unicode

I have a UTF8 table in MySQL containing names, with all types of text (numeric, capitals, greek, cycrillic etc).

```
---------------
ID   Name
---------------
001  Jane Smith
002  John Doe
003  Джемз Смис
004  Пэтра Смис
005  "Groove" Holme
006  99er Dude
```

How can I select only the cyrillic names? (records 003 and 004)

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answer below, which looked like it would be correct, but didn't work. More research turned up this in the documentation:

> Warning
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are
>   not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte
>   character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by
>   their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal
>   even if a given collation treats them as equal.

**EDIT EDIT, A SOLUTION**

I solved this by adding an extra field to my database which stores the script type, eg Cyrillic, Thai etc. Then a ran a batch process in PHP that detects the script and stores the information in the database.

To detect the script in PHP, use Unicode regex functions. See this page:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if it covers all characters, but you should be able to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name REGEXP '[Α-Ωα-ωА-Яа-я]'
```

which will return all entries containing at least one cyrillic or greek character

**EDIT**

Check "Warning" in OP's question about REGEXP/RLIKE working in byte-wise fashion so they might not work for multi-byte character sets.

Comment: @Doesn't work, see edit to the question, thanks for nudging me along to the documentation.

Comment: @soupagain hm, no problem :) but it works for me, when i tried it (with your names), but i see it may not work everywhere/every time

Comment: @boobiq hm. SELECT id, name_en, address FROM marina_office WHERE address REGEXP '[й]'; returns `66420 Ле Баркарес` as marina_office.address. Seems like it compares by single byte =\

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov yes, see OP's edit in question about REGEXP/RLIKE being byte-wise operators.